# loading a project-wide CSS file inside an app-specific CSS file in Django

Tags: css, django

I'm working on a Django 1.10.5 project. I have a number of apps, each of which has an app-specific css file which must import a css file common to all the apps. But the import isn't working unless I put the common css file in each app's static folder (defeats the point).

In the app template I have

`<link rel="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app1/css/app1.css' %}"/>`

And my settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static-storage"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)), "static-serve")
```

The common css file is in `static-storage/css`. I have tried running `collectstatic` but it does nothing...right now `DEBUG=True`. Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: create a template with custom block which have all the common css included and include the template where ever you want

Comment: You mean that `{% static 'css/common.css' %}` doesn't work?

Comment: The problem is that I have a style sheet `app1.css` with `@import url(path_to_common.css)` inside it...stylesheet `app1.css` loads fine via `{% static 'app1/css/app1.css' %}` but `common.css` does not get imported unless I put it in the same directory as `app1.css` which is not ideal since `common.css` gets used by multiple apps...